# Copy a user defined size struct member array to a file

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct, malloc

I have an array of char which is a member of a struct.
I want this array to be with a dynamic user defined size, and finally to copy the struct's contents into a file.

The way I know to create a user defined size array is with malloc, which returns a pointer to the array.

The issue arises when I want to write this data into a file.
The actual data written takes into account sizeof(char*), and not the actual string.

```
struct database_s {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
};


fwrite(ptr_to_struct, sizeof(struct database_s), 1, file);
```

The question is how to copy a user defined size array into a file.
Thanks.

Comment: Writing raw structs to files is a bad idea in general. Now you have to deal with size issues (how big is `int` on this platform? 2 bytes? 4? 8?), endianness (little endian vs. big endian), and padding.

Comment: How about using strlen to get the size you need?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, so it means I will have to write the data to the file in chunks ?

Comment: In any case writing memory pointers `char *name` and `char *email` to file is useless. You need to write the *data*.

Comment: Yes, but how should I do this? field by field is my only option?

Comment: I suggest you do some research about *serialization*.

Comment: if you're looking for a one-liner to write all the data I don't think you're going to find it. Your data isn't contiguous in memory.